# Junção de 2 Consultas Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-entities

Estou utilizando o banco de dados mySql. Tenho 2 tabelas uma de perguntas e as opções relacionadas à pergunta. Para cada acesso que eu fizer ao sistema preciso pegar as perguntas de forma randomica e obviamente as opções relacionadas. Eu achei no google uma forma de pegar as perguntas de forma randomica pois o mySql não tem o Guid como no Sql server. Abaixo o código:

```cs
var teste = (from q in db.Questoes orderby rnd.Next() select q).Take(2)
```

Agora como eu faço o join desta consulta com a minha tabela de opções? O join é  feito com o campo `Questoes.Id` e `Opcoes.QuestoesId`

```
public class QuestaoModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    public string Pergunta { get; set; }
    public int TemaId { get; set; }
    public virtual TemaModel Tema { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OpcaoModel> Opcoes { get; set; }
    public virtual RespostaModel Resposta { get; set; }
}

public class OpcaoModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string opcaoResposta { get; set; }
    public int QuestaoId  { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestaoModel Questao { get; set; }
}
```

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Não é só dar um `include` da relação??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pelo que descreveu penso que seja isso:**

```
var teste = 
    (from q in db.Questoes 
    join op in db.Opcoes on q.Id equals op.QuestoesId 
    orderby rnd.Next() select q)
    .Take(2)
```

Comment: Mauro a sua solução funcionou mas só tem um  detalhe. No meu select um uso um modelo que é o seguinte:  public class QuestaoOpcaoModel
    {
        public int QuestaoId { get; set; }
        public string QuestaoPergunta { get; set; }
        public int OpcaoId { get; set; }
        public string OpcaoDescricao { get; set; }
    } E quando faço isso carrega as 2 perguntas mas com apenas 1 opção cada. E cadas pergunta tem 5 opções. Como faço para não perde-las?

Comment: Se funcionou aceite a reposta Marcelo, qualquer coisa que não ficou como quer diga e eu edito a resposta

Comment: <br/> O problea que estou tendo é no select pois eu carrego uma model. abaixo está ela: <br/> language:c#  public class QuestaoOpcaoModel
    {
        public int QuestaoId { get; set; }
        public string QuestaoPergunta { get; set; }
        public int OpcaoId { get; set; }
        public string OpcaoDescricao { get; set; }
    } <br/> Mas ao fazer isto aparece as 2 perguntas mas com apenas 1 opção cada e na verdade são 5 opções cada pergunta. Como pode fazer para resolver este problema?

Comment: Mas isso já é outra pergunta, tem de criar outra pergunta, não faz parte da mesma.

Comment: ok. vou fazer então

Comment: confirme como correta a reposta que dei Marcelo

Answer (score 2):

Tente usar algo como `db.Questoes.Include(i => i.Opcoes)` para trazer as opções no resultado.

Comment: O OP está a utilizar outro tipo de estilo no LINQ dele.

Comment: Creio que o resultado seria o mesmo pois é possível mesclar os dois estilos de consulta.

Comment: Sim, tem toda a razão, só referi isso porque é boa prática adotar um estilo, misturar vários pode ser confuso para a leitura.

Comment: Concordo com você.